# how to repeat left and right part of the image using 9 patch

Tags: android-drawable, android-tablayout, nine-patch, android-background

i have an image stepper arrows image like [Actual image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZaej.png)
i want to set as background for tab layout but because it is background image, its width getting stretch on bigger width devices and image looks [stretch image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYRfC.png)
is there any solution for that, or any 9 patch way to repeat only left and right part of image